# Pandas: Reindex Unsorts Dataframe

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, reindex

I'm having some trouble sorting and then resetting my Index in Pandas:

```
dfm = dfm.sort(['delt'],ascending=False)
dfm = dfm.reindex(index=range(1,len(dfm)))
```

The dataframe returns unsorted after I reindex.  My ultimate goal is to have a sorted dataframe with index numbers from 1 --> len(dfm) so if there's a better way to do that, I wouldn't mind,

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Instead of reindexing, just change the actual index:

```
dfm.index = range(1,len(dfm) + 1)
```

Then that wont change the order, just the index

Comment: Piling on to Ryan's answer: df.index = df.index.sort_values()

Answer (score 8):

I think you're misunderstanding what `reindex` does. It uses the passed index to select values  along the axis passed, then fills with `NaN` wherever your passed index doesn't match up with the current index. What you're interested in is just setting the index to something else:

```
In [12]: df = DataFrame(randn(10, 2), columns=['a', 'delt'])

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
       a   delt
0  0.222 -0.964
1  0.038 -0.367
2  0.293  1.349
3  0.604 -0.855
4 -0.455 -0.594
5  0.795  0.013
6 -0.080 -0.235
7  0.671  1.405
8  0.436  0.415
9  0.840  1.174

In [14]: df.reindex(index=arange(1, len(df) + 1))
Out[14]:
        a   delt
1   0.038 -0.367
2   0.293  1.349
3   0.604 -0.855
4  -0.455 -0.594
5   0.795  0.013
6  -0.080 -0.235
7   0.671  1.405
8   0.436  0.415
9   0.840  1.174
10    NaN    NaN

In [16]: df.index = arange(1, len(df) + 1)

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
        a   delt
1   0.222 -0.964
2   0.038 -0.367
3   0.293  1.349
4   0.604 -0.855
5  -0.455 -0.594
6   0.795  0.013
7  -0.080 -0.235
8   0.671  1.405
9   0.436  0.415
10  0.840  1.174
```

Remember, if you want `len(df)` to be in the index you have to add 1 to the endpoint since Python *doesn't include endpoints when constructing ranges*.

Comment: Like most answers about `reindex`, this again shows how terrible a name `reindex` is for what this method does.

Comment: @BrenBarn Eh, maybe. What would you have called it?

Comment: @BrenBarn I have a feeling it may get worse with `set_index` :S tricky.

Comment: @PhillipCloud: I would call it something like `get`, because all it does is get elements based on their existing index values.  `reindex` implies you are setting a new index for existing values.

Comment: The Pandas ``reindex`` function does something like Excel's `VLOOKUP`.